# How to replace text inside a [] in a string?

Tags: javascript

I need to replace a text inside a string.

eg: The text will be

`Hello! This is a test [query] which i am using for [transformation]`

And what i need is to extract the string's inside [] with another string mapping object i have. which is in the form

```
{
"query":'ab',
"transformation":'cd'
}
```

So the result string will be
`Hello! This is a test [ab] which i am using for [cd]`

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: i tried using some custom regex logic but i really got lost :D

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service, so please add your most promising approach, describe the problems you have with it and we might be able to fix it.

Comment: does the mapping object contain all cases?  what should be filled if the string doesn't exist in mapping object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var input = "Hello! This is a test [query] which i am using for [transformation]"

const query = {
"query":'ab',
"transformation":'cd'
}

Object.keys(query).forEach(key => {
  input = input.replace(key, query[key])
})

console.log(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const str =
  'Hello! This is a test [query] which i am using for [transformation]';

const mapping = {
  query: 'ab',
  transformation: 'cd'
};

const res = Object.keys(mapping).reduce(
  (modified, key) => modified.replace(key, mapping[key]),
  str
);

console.log(res);
```